# How to get element from slider's DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to set style for first and last element of slider(5 active elements).I have code, but problem in that i cant get this two elements.

I used this one(yes, i use slick slider)

```
var sliderTour = document.getElementById("slider-tour");
var slickActive = sliderTour.getElementsByClassName("slick-active");
```

but i only get HTMLCollection [], and when i use

```
var first = slickActive[0];
var last = slickActive[slickActive.length - 1];
console.log(first, last);
```

i get undefined and cant set style for first and last item of active elements of slider

and there is some html code of slider

```html
<section class="slider-tour" id="slider-tour">
 <div class="slicker-booking slick-initialized slick-slider">
  <div class="slick-list draggable">
   <div class="slick-track">
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

I want to get first and last elements and set them css style like background with opacity

```html
.slick-active:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

If you have easier way to set the background that i want, you can say it instead of my way. Thank you

Comment: *"but i only get HTMLCollection"* With that code and markup, you shouldn't even be getting that, you should be getting an error. You've used `getElementById` but the element doesn't have an `id`, it has a `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i only get HTMLCollection

With that code and markup, you shouldn't even be getting that, you should be getting an error. You've used `getElementById` but the element doesn't have an `id`, it has a `class`.

You can get the first element with the class `slider-tour` via `querySelector`, and then get all of the `slick-active` elements within it via `querySelectorAll`:

```
const active = document.querySelector(".slider-tour").querySelectorAll(".slick-active");
const first = active[0];
const last = active[active.length - 1];
```

Live example:

```js
const active = document.querySelector(".slider-tour").querySelectorAll(".slick-active");
const first = active[0];
const last = active[active.length - 1];
first.style.color = "green";
last.style.color = "blue";
```

```html
Note I've put text in the active elements so you can see the color change I'm applying via JavaScript:

<section class="slider-tour">
 <div class="slicker-booking slick-initialized slick-slider">
  <div class="slick-list draggable">
   <div class="slick-track">
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active">a0</div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active">a1</div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active">a2</div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active">a3</div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-active">a4</div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
     <div class="slider-item slick-slide slick-cloned"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes, it work in your snippet. But when i use it code in my project, i got only NodeList[] including empty length, how can it be?

That is why i used getElementById, for start i got div with slider-tour id and after that i got all slick-active class elements

Comment: And sorry, i show html code without id. It seem like 
<section class="slider-tour" id="slider-tour>

Comment: @NickolasDzR - If the `NodeList` is empty, it's because there aren't any `.slick-active` elements in the slider as of when you run that code.

Comment: When i added window.onload function, it worked. Thanks

Comment: @NickolasDzR - Good deal! FWIW: Using `onload` is almost never a good idea. Just put your `script` at the end of the document body, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. That way, all of the elements defined by the markup above it exist as of when the script runs. (Or, on any modern browser, mark the script with the `defer` attribute and the browser won't try to run it until it's finished parsing the HTML.)